# comparing two lists with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say that I have these two lists of Persons.  The Person object has FirstName, LastName, and Age properties.

### List A

David Smith, 38
David Smith, 38
Susan Johnson, 23

### List B

David Smith, 38
David Smith, 38
Susan Johnson, 23
Daniel Wallace, 55

I want to see if A is a subset of B by comparing the three properties.  No, in this case I do not have a  unique ID for each person.

EDIT: There can be duplicates in List A (David Smith, 38).  List B should have the duplicates for it to qualify as a super set of B.

Comment: Are there any other properties? Does `Person` implement `IEquatable<Person>` appropriately?

Comment: My class isn't exactly Person.  But no, I am reading up on IEquatable.  Then what LINQ operator do I use?  Contains?

Answer (score 6):

Once you've got a class which implements `IEquatable<T>` or `IEqualityComparer<T>`, it's easy to do the rest with `Except` and `Any`:

```
if (collectionA.Except(collectionB).Any())
{
    // There are elements in A which aren't in B
}
```

or

```
if (collectionA.Except(collectionB, equalityComparer).Any())
{
    // There are elements in A which aren't in B
}
```

EDIT: If there are duplicates, you'd probably want to group each collection, then check the counts:

```
var groupedA = collectionA.GroupBy(p => p,
                                   (Value, g) => new { Value, Count = g.Count() });
var groupedB = collectionB.GroupBy(p => p,
                                   (Value, g) => new { Value, Count = g.Count() });
var extras = from a in groupedA
             join b in groupedB on a.Value equals b.Value into match
             where !match.Any() || a.Count > match.First().Count
             select a;

// ListA has at least one entry not in B, or with more duplicates than in B
if (extras.Any())
{
}
```

This is pretty horrible though...

Comment: Would this work with duplicates?  I fixed the original post to include duplicates.  For list B to qualify as a super set of A, it needs to have all the duplicates.

Comment: So you mean if List A contains "David Smith, 38" 3 times then List B needs to contain it at least 3 times as well?

Comment: Yes.  I know it's a horrible example.  But for my situation, B needs to be inclusive of all the duplicates.

Comment: @user79284: Try the edit in my answer - but there may well be simpler ways. (And in future, please include *crucial* details like this to start with.)

Answer (score 2):

If `Person` does not implement `IEquatable<Person>` the "brute force" method would be:

```
var isSubset = listA.All(pa => listB.Any(pb => pb.FirstName == pa.FirstName &&
                                               pb.LastName == pa.LastName &&
                                               pb.Age == pb.Age
                                        ) 
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join

```
var l1 = new List<Person>();//Subset 
var l2 = new List<Person>();//Set of all values

var res = from l1 in lst1
                      join l2 in lst2 
                      on l1.Value equals l2.Value
                      select new { result = l1 };
```

And compare count.If it is euqual, then Set contains subset

```
bool flag = res.Count()==lst1.Count();
```